# 22.04.1 LTS Network Unclaimed for wireless adapter and ethernet port

Tags: wireless, 22.04, ethernet, adapter

I lost all ability to connect to the internet on Linux Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. Sudo lshw -class network shows both the wireless adapter and network port as 'Unclaimed'. Read in other posts that means the hardware doesn't have the drivers. I don't know where to find them or how to install them without connectivity. Please help.

Comment: If you boot into an earlier kernel version at the GRUB menu, do they work?

Comment: Don't know how. Sorry. Very new to Linux. I can try now.

Comment: Think I found it. Tried older kernel. No change.

Comment: Switched to another kernel. I think there were technically three versions in the grub menu. Wifi is back! Good to know. Just wish I could still use on external monitor. Newer kernel let's me mirror onto a TV but wireless disappears. Old kernel does the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot into the latest kernel where the wireless doesn’t work. Run the command:

```
uname -r
```

Make careful note of the exact kernel version; as an example, 5.15.0-99-generic.

Also run:

```
sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status
```

I am quite confident that you’ll find that the package is not installed.

Boot back into the earlier kernel version where the wireless *does* work and run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-99-generic
```

Of course, substitute the kernel version you noted above.

After the installation is complete, reboot. You should be all set.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Bonus points if you can help me output to my external tv monitor. HDMI not outputting signal

Comment: Please start a new question about the HDMI. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Done and done. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help :) !