# Internet lost since regular 20.04 update

Tags: 20.04, wireless, internet, wired

Last 20.04 update after rebooting stopped me from accessing internet through WiFi or Ethernet, any idea what could be done?
Many thanks to all for your help
6ou

Comment: Check in terminal `dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1445961/22-04-1-lts-network-unclaimed-for-wireless-adapter-and-ethernet-port/1446024?noredirect=1#comment2523864_1446024