nmcli disconnected and can’t connect to wifi
Like the title says when I type in ‘’’nmcli general status ‘’’it says it’s disconnected it does show all available networks with ‘’’ connection show ‘’’but when I try to connect to one it says no device found or not compatible
The reason I need to connect this way is that there is an issue after an update and I’m trying to fix it but without internet access I can’t
Version 24.04.1 lts desktop
Idk what to do I can’t find anything on the web that helps

Solved 22.04.1 LTS Network Unclaimed for wireless adapter and ethernet port

Additionally, provide us information about your system's hardware as well.  You may need to run lshw -class network and add that as output to your question as an edit for us to see what hardware is on the system.

Recovery console is very basic, and doesn't have the system fully operational (thus a front-end or user facing tool like NM won't be available, you need to boot the system fully first).   What release you're using allow us to better help you, as we're limited to details you provide.   You've not provided release details so we can't know your defaults; but at runlevel 1 networking hasn't yet started; ie. you can fix file-system issues locally but not do more

You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details; the starting point to understanding what software you're using.  Runlevel 1 is a linux run state; allowing access to local file-system fixes (using man runlevel can show details) or local rescue/fix..  You need to reach runlevel 2 before networking is started, ie. boot your system as runlevel 1 is for fixes only (ie. recovery of problems locally).   To know what you mean by recovery console details of what you're running need to be known; thus why I'm speaking using general terms that apply to all, rather than specific for you.

I found an answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1445961/22-04-1-lts-network-unclaimed-for-wireless-adapter-and-ethernet-port
All hail this dude
